# Java: How to create an infinite loop in a Class without overriding main

Tags: java, loops

I have a class that needs an infinite loop to function properly, however upon its creation, it does not allow for the succeeding code to continue.
How would I create an infinite loop within a class, while still allowing the following code in main to execute?

Here's my code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
class Z{
    public Z(int x,int y){
        JWindow j=new JWindow();
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.setLocation(x,y);
        j.setSize(100,100);

        while(true) {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }
}
public class exampleCode{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        f.setResizable(false);
        new Z(100,100);
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: read about threads. you need to run it in another thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about Threads, Multi-threading in Java.

Since your program is single-threaded your infinite while loop will prevent any further code execution (other than that inside `while` block). To avoid this you should run your infinite loop in a new thread.

There are many ways/styles to achieve this and this is one of the shortest:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your infinite loop here
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!